# Fetch data from multi dimensional struct

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I am new to mat lab and I am facing trouble with structs.
I want to fetch the data from a multi dimensional sturct `tree.frame` (1x2913 struct) and the frame has data 2913x5.

[image: time.frame struct]

[image: frame data]

How do I extract the field `ms` from the `tree.frame`?

Comment: I’m sure this is explained in the documentation. `time.frame(index).ms`.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all the values in the "ms" column by using the following code: `time.frame(:).ms`. If you need a specific row of the data, then you can use the code suggested by Cris Luengo.